# WSB Not Working

Tags: windows, sql, windows-server-2016

Trying to get WSB working on a server running SQL.  The current setup is this.

- Server OS is 2019
- Backup target is an iSCSI target configured on a NAS, its setup as a local drive on the server
- Backups are configured to be sent to this drive nightly.  This is so that I can do incremental backups over the network, instead of overwriting it each time like with SMB.

Error encountered in WSB: "A volume Shadow Copy Service operation failed.  Please check "VSS" and "SPP" application event.  Detailed error:  Too much time elapsed between freezing a transaction and thawing the transaction manager."

I also get this error in the Windows application log at the same time that the backup failed.

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: Windows Server Backup Error
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 2
P2: 1
P3: 0x807800a1
P4: 0x80042329
P5: 0x80780064
P6: 0x8078001d
P7: 0x80780064
P8: 0x00000000
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup\WBEngine.0.etl
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERFF5A.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERFF5B.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERFF85.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERFFA5.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_2_486ee5de5c8fc6eae636bbeee8596fd140becc_00000000_cab_0921ffb4

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 99a05e2d-bea0-4d60-9bf5-8fb63f08400a
Report Status: 100
Hashed bucket: 
Cab Guid: 0
```

I haven't tried much because I can't seem to find much info on this that isn't really old.  One suggestion says to mark the Windows partition as active, but that will make it unbootable from what I remember, so I'm not going to do that.

Another says to set VSS to automatic startup, but that doesn't work, and I haven't had any errors related to it starting from what I've seen.

I have this configuration setup at several other sites and it works without issue.  The only difference between this site and others is the amount of data.  This site has around 12 TB of data on this server, and they aren't large files, its millions of smaller files.  So what I'm wondering is if WSB is really the best option for this, or if I should be using something more robust like Acronis.  I'm not sure of what the limitations of VSS and WSB are.  Perhaps when its trying to create the shadow copy for the backup there are so many files that it can't finish before what Windows has configured as the timeout period?

EDIT: Changed server OS from 2016 to 2019, that was a typo.

Comment: How many shadow copies are there for the volume that is failing backup? How many incremental backups are there? What is the write performance of the volume?

Comment: There was one shadow copy, I removed it and I'm going to see if that fixes it when it fires later on tonight.  There are no incremental backups, right now the backups are overwritten each night using robocopy (we inherited this setup).  Do you  mean the write performance of the iSCSI target volume?